# Android GoogleDrive Stream

Tags: android, google-drive-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover video url through google drive api in order to stream the video in an html5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331837/recover-video-url-through-google-drive-api-in-order-to-stream-the-video-in-an-ht)

Overview:
I'm working on my android application for video streaming.  The video file is stored on Google Drive.  I created the URL link to the video file using "share - anyone with the link" feature in GoogleDrive

Question:
How to get the direct stream URL from a video shared link on Google Drive to my android device?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331837/recover-video-url-through-google-drive-api-in-order-to-stream-the-video-in-an-ht