# How to play HTML5 Video for a public mp4 file that is on Google Drive?

Tags: video, html5-video, google-drive-api

I want to be able to play public mp4 files stored on my  Google drive using html5 Video tags or custom html5 video players. This [file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-fYJN-c4UDjZjg0LV9XeTFpTjQ/edit?usp=sharing)  is playable on Chrome when you click on the link but it fails when  you play it with html5 video player like the simple html5 code below. When I put the same file on my apache web server and point to my apache web server url for this file , the html5 video code  works fine and the movie plays in the browser.

How do I play this as html5 video in my html5 video player using google drive sdk ? Please  note that I do ot wish to use the google' video player but only simple html5 Video tags.

```
    <body>
<video src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-fYJN-c4UDjZjg0LV9XeTFpTjQ/edit?usp=sharing" autoplay>
      </video></body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover video url through google drive api in order to stream the video in an html5 player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331837/recover-video-url-through-google-drive-api-in-order-to-stream-the-video-in-an-ht)