# get videoplayback link from GDrive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm using GDrive to host my files, and I want to embed that video on my webpage via videojs, And I want temporary link like redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?xxx to embed on page, And I tried to get video link via API, and public method like `https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileID}` and `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={fileID}` but in result I get `xxx-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/xxx` link structure, please guide me how can I generate link as I want

Comment: I think you are on the right track, as stated in a related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10331967/5995040) you have to use the **`downloadUrl`** which gives a URL to the actual file. Take note that **`downloadUrl`** is available in Google Drive v2 - [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get). If the file is publicly shared, the URL is directly accessible but if not, user will have to user OAuth 2.0 to access the url. Lastly, also stated in the link above " that URL only works momentarily. So it's not usable for every use-case." Hope this info helps.

Comment: I tried it, but returns as i mention in question, url is something like `xxx-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/xxx` see the SS http://prntscr.com/d8icbp , I want something like this `xx.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?prems`

Comment: and its my privacy setting for this video http://prntscr.com/d8ids2

Comment: but when I play this video in any player, downloadable urls i`https://r8---sn-2uja-3ips.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=73ea3cad0ba74e41&itag=18&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=explorer&ip=182.186.119.65&ipbits=8&expire=1479415806&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=5F70C96E729B53D2A8225221A189A1F5DE3AAE02.80E600D2C7A135851D24CE65A6B707AFFA35611A&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-2uja-3ips&ms=au&mt=1479401271&mv=m&pl=17&cpn=gJRJqlynlvKSHVgL&c=WEB&cver=1.20161116` through IDM download

Comment: actualy I don't want that anyone can view my code and copy my link, this link, as I need is temporary, I require this