# Python: download files from google drive using url

Tags: python, download, google-drive-api, urllib2, pydrive

I am trying to download files from google drive and all I have is the drive's URL.

I have read about google API that talks about some `drive_service` and `MedioIO`, which also requires some credentials( mainly JSON `file/OAuth`). But I am unable to get any idea about how it is working.

Also, tried `urllib2.urlretrieve`, but my case is to get files from the drive. Tried `wget` too but no use.

Tried `PyDrive` library. It has good upload functions to drive but no download options.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If by "drive's url" you mean the **shareable link** of a file on Google Drive, then the following might help:

```
import sys
import requests


def download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=1"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params={"id": file_id}, stream=True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = {"id": file_id, "confirm": token}
        response = session.get(URL, params=params, stream=True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)


def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith("download_warning"):
            return value

    return None


def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        file_id = sys.argv[1]
        destination = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        file_id = "TAKE_ID_FROM_SHAREABLE_LINK"
        destination = "DESTINATION_FILE_ON_YOUR_DISK"
    print(f"dowload {file_id} to {destination}")
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The snipped does not use *pydrive*, nor the Google Drive SDK, though. It uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) module (which is, somehow, an alternative to *urllib2*).

When downloading large files from Google Drive, a single GET request is not sufficient. A second one is needed - see [wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225039/6770522).

Comment: This gives me a 404-not found, using the ID of a public shared file. Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Comment: How can I download files from Google Drive given links, for example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I05c4-d9OsNwGZnLx85fR8dnX-yVoTWe/view

Comment: @turdus-merula Anyway to get the downloading file name as it is stored in drive?

Comment: NVM, I got it by doing this: re.search(r'filename\=\"(.*)\"', response.headers['Content-Disposition']).group(1)

Comment: Don't work and just silently downloads 4,0K file without warning or error

Example link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qLcYyJmiz0TXdaTExNcW03ejA

Comment: How can we get the name of the document from the link

Comment: seems like something has changed behind the scenes and the token stuff does not quite work anymore. However, simply always including `confirm=1` as parameter seems to be a workaround.

Comment: This isn't working for me either.  I can't see where to include "confirm=1".  There doesn't seem to be an argument named 'confirm' to 'download_file_from_google_drive'.  No matter what I try, I always get a big bunch of HTML rather than the small file I'm hoping to download.

Comment: This works for me by including "confirm=1". I'm not sure why it doesn't work for other people. Note that I'm only downloading .csv files.

Comment: Hi @CryptoFool, I had your same question and figured it out. Remove the code getting token and replace the variable `token` with `1` in this line: `params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : 1 }`

Answer (score 85):

I recommend the [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown) package.

```
pip install gdown
```

Take your share link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P1L--7Wd2vNm9zMTJWOGxobkU/view?usp=sharing

and grab the id - eg. 1TLNdIufzwesDbyr_nVTR7Zrx9oRHLM_N by pressing the download button (look for at the link), and swap it in after the id below.

```
import gdown

url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B9P1L--7Wd2vNm9zMTJWOGxobkU'
output = '20150428_collected_images.tgz'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
```

Comment: Importantly, if you create the link by  "Share" or "Get shareable link", the URL doesn't work - you must replace in the URL "open" to "uc". In other words, `drive.google.com/open?id= ...` to `drive.google.com/uc?id= ...`

Comment: I tried to do as @AgileBean stated, but my link looks like this ```https://drive.google.com/file/d/3Xxk5lJSr...UV5eX9M/view?usp=sharing``` so it did not work. So instead, I used the ID parameter ```gdown --id 3Xxk5lJSr...UV5eX9M``` where ```3Xxk5lJSr...UV5eX9M``` is the file id that you can easily extract from the file's link.

Comment: The best one. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: it doesn't work.... even for public files. I find it ridiculous that the output from this, running on python is "you may be able to use the browser". Now I only need to download the library that converts Python to a human who knows how to operate a browser and has hands for keyboard and mouse....

Comment: Worked for me using when pasted the link that appears after pressing the "Download" button on google drive web page

Comment: Worked perfectly, I had a zipfile that contained a CSV dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 60):

Having had similar needs many times, I made an extra simple class `GoogleDriveDownloader` starting on the snippet from @user115202 above. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/ndrplz/google-drive-downloader).

You can also install it through pip:

```
pip install googledrivedownloader
```

Then usage is as simple as:

```
from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as gdd

gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE__vIKouTKyIDjEq',
                                    dest_path='./data/mnist.zip',
                                    unzip=True)
```

This snippet will download an archive shared in Google Drive. In this case `1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE__vIKouTKyIDjEq` is the id of the sharable link got from Google Drive.

Comment: can't retrieve file ... `'open(/content/data.json').read()` returns `'<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Not Found</H1>\n<H2>Error 404</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'`

Comment: @Raksha It's difficult to understand the issue from your comment. If you still encounter this problem, please open a proper issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/ndrplz/google-drive-downloader/issues)

Comment: What modification should be done to download this zip file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qLcYyJmiz0TXdaTExNcW03ejA

Just using 0B4qLcYyJmiz0TXdaTExNcW03ejA not work.

Comment: You need to add `requests` to the requirements.

Comment: What if I want to access a restricted file using a Gmail id and password?

Comment: My files are in a folder and the shared link of the folder is `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14gKg6QW3TnwnaHoYTxxTr6NzgQWqJufa?usp=sharing`, but I can not download this folder using this method.

Comment: I had `GoogleDriveDownloader` working just fine for me, but now it appears to have stopped. I'm not sure if something changed on Google's end: the response contains 200 OK but does not contain any cookies, so the attempt to extract the token breaks and it can't proceed past that.

Comment: I removed the first call in the download method about retrieving the token, and now everything seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an easy way to do it with no third-party libraries and a service account.

pip install `google-api-core` and `google-api-python-client`

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import io

credz = {} #put json credentials her from service account or the like
# More info: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credz)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
#fh = io.BytesIO() # this can be used to keep in memory
fh = io.FileIO('file.tar.gz', 'wb') # this can be used to write to disk
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

Comment: good example of using json credentials w/google api client

Comment: Thank you, this is best working answer as on date for downloading from Google Drive API using Python.

Answer (score 10):

`PyDrive` allows you to download a file with the function `GetContentFile()`. You can find the function's documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#download-file-content).

See example below:

```
# Initialize GoogleDriveFile instance with file id.
file_obj = drive.CreateFile({'id': '<your file ID here>'})
file_obj.GetContentFile('cats.png') # Download file as 'cats.png'.
```

This code assumes that you have an authenticated `drive` object, the docs on this can be found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#authentication-in-two-lines) and [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html).

In the general case this is done like so:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
# Create local webserver which automatically handles authentication.
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

# Create GoogleDrive instance with authenticated GoogleAuth instance.
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Info on silent authentication on a server can be found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#automatic-and-custom-authentication-with-settings-yaml) and involves writing a `settings.yaml` (example: [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#building-your-own-authentication-flow)) in which you save the authentication details.

Comment: Your answer is more interesting

Comment: first link broken :(

Comment: @Joe fixed the link!

Comment: @RobinNabel every link in the answer is now dead

Answer (score 8):

[There's in the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#python) a function that downloads a file when we provide an ID of the file to download,

```
from __future__ import print_function

import io

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload


def download_file(real_file_id):
    """Downloads a file
    Args:
        real_file_id: ID of the file to download
    Returns : IO object with location.

    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()

    try:
        # create drive api client
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        file_id = real_file_id

        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        file = None

    return file.getvalue()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_file(real_file_id='1KuPmvGq8yoYgbfW74OENMCB5H0n_2Jm9')
```

---

This bears the question:

> **How do we get the file ID to download the file?**

Generally speaking, a URL from a shared file from Google Drive looks like this

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HV6vf8pB-EYnjcJcH65eGZVMa2v2tcMh/view?usp=sharing
```

where `1HV6vf8pB-EYnjcJcH65eGZVMa2v2tcMh` corresponds to fileID.

You can simply copy it from the URL or, if you prefer, it's also possible to create a function to get the fileID from the URL.

For instance, given the following `url = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HV6vf8pB-EYnjcJcH65eGZVMa2v2tcMh/view?usp=sharing`,

```
def url_to_id(url):
    x = url.split("/")
    return x[5]
```

Printing x will give

```
['https:', '', 'drive.google.com', 'file', 'd', '1HV6vf8pB-EYnjcJcH65eGZVMa2v2tcMh', 'view?usp=sharing']
```

And so, as we want to return the 6th array value, we use `x[5]`.

Comment: This official google example has potential `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getvalue'` in case of HttpError.

Comment: @4xy there are ways to solve it, like checking if file is `None` before `return file.getvalue()`

Comment: There is always a solution... Like e.g. removing try except

Answer (score 5):

```
import requests

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id , 'confirm': 1 }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_id = 'TAKE ID FROM SHAREABLE LINK'
    destination = 'DESTINATION FILE ON YOUR DISK'
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```

Just repeating the accepted answer but adding `confirm=1` parameter so it always downloads even if the file is too big

Answer (score 3):

This has also been described above,

```
   from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
   gauth = GoogleAuth()
   gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
   drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

This creates its own server too do the dirty work of authenticating

```
   file_obj = drive.CreateFile({'id': '<Put the file ID here>'})
   file_obj.GetContentFile('Demo.txt')
```

This downloads the file

Answer (score 2):

```
# Importing [PyDrive][1] OAuth
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

def download_tracking_file_by_id(file_id, download_dir):
    gauth = GoogleAuth(settings_file='../settings.yaml')
    # Try to load saved client credentials
    gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("../credentials.json")
    if gauth.credentials is None:
        # Authenticate if they're not there
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    elif gauth.access_token_expired:
        # Refresh them if expired
        gauth.Refresh()
    else:
        # Initialize the saved creds
        gauth.Authorize()
    # Save the current credentials to a file
    gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("../credentials.json")

    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

    logger.debug("Trying to download file_id " + str(file_id))
    file6 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
    file6.GetContentFile(download_dir+'mapmob.zip')
    zipfile.ZipFile(download_dir + 'test.zip').extractall(UNZIP_DIR)
    tracking_data_location = download_dir + 'test.json'
    return tracking_data_location
```

The above function downloads the file given the file_id to a specified downloads folder. Now the question remains, how to get the file_id? Simply split the url by id= to get the file_id.

```
file_id = url.split("id=")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using google Colaboratory: https://colab.research.google.com/

Suppose your sharable link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12hiI0NK7M0KEfscMfyBaLT9gxcZMleeu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102608702203033509854&rtpof=true&sd=true

all you need is id that is 12hiI0NK7M0KEfscMfyBaLT9gxcZMleeu

command in cell

```
!gdown 12hiI0NK7M0KEfscMfyBaLT9gxcZMleeu
```

run the cell and you will see that file is downloaded in /content/Amazon_Reviews.xlsx

Note: one should know how to use Google colab

Answer (score 0):

This example is based on an similar to RayB, but keeps the file in memory
and is a little simpler, and you can paste it into colab and it works.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import oauth2client.client
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

def download_gdrive(id):
  creds = oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
  return service.files().get_media(fileId=id).execute()

a = download_gdrive("1F-yaQB8fdsfsdafm2l8WFjhEiYSHZrCcr")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the accepted solution for a long period, but now google has changed the download warning response so it does not work anymore.

I am now using the API as it is a safer way to ensure it won't suddenly stop, but I could also make it work parsing the response HTML looking for the download url as following:

```
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.action = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "form":
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == "id" and value == "download-form":
                    for name, value in attrs:
                        if name == "action":
                            self.action = value

DOWNLOAD_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download'
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(file_url, params={'id': id}, stream=True)

content_type = response.headers['content-type']
if content_type == 'text/html; charset=utf-8':
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(response.text)
    download_url = parser.action
    response = session.post(download_url, stream=True)
    
file = response.content
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version for 2023 + generator for tracking progress

```
import requests


def download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination, chunk_size=32768):
    url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()
    params = {'id': file_id, 'confirm': 1}
    response = session.get(url, params=params, stream=True)

    for i, chunk_size_ in save_response_content(response, destination, chunk_size):
        yield i, chunk_size_


def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None


def save_response_content(response, destination, chunk_size):
    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for i, chunk in enumerate(response.iter_content(chunk_size)):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                yield i, chunk_size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_id = '...'
    destination = '...'
    for i, chunk_size in download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination):
        print(i, chunk_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in the **link** to download via HTTP, the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files) and most clients provide a `webContentLink` field containing it (note the file permissions to use it)

Answer (score -3):

You can install  https://pypi.org/project/googleDriveFileDownloader/

`pip install googleDriveFileDownloader`

And download the file, here is the sample code to download

```py
from googleDriveFileDownloader import googleDriveFileDownloader
a = googleDriveFileDownloader()
a.downloadFile("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1O4x8rwGJAh8gRo8sjm0kuKFf6vCEm93G&export=download")
```

Comment: `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?`