# Python: How to find google drive filetype?

Tags: python, drive

I'm currently using the session.get() code found at this stackoverflow. When I save the drive files they don't have a filetype suffix, so I have to add one manually to based on file type to open it. Is there a way I can parse the chunk and get filetype variable or maybe even search by hexcode? Better method?

```
import requests
def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
    params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
    response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        file_id = 'TAKE ID FROM SHAREABLE LINK'
        destination = 'DESTINATION FILE ON YOUR DISK'
        download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```

Source: [Python: download files from google drive using url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url)
via @user6770522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used beatifulSoup and findAll to grab the 'title' tag. Then applied it to destination by os path join.

```
for filename in soup.findAll('title'):
    link = filename.string
    filename = link.replace(' - Google Drive','')
    destination = os.path.join(dir,filename)
    file_path = os.path.join(year_name, destination)
    drive_pull.download_file_from_google_drive(url_id, file_path)
```