# How to get content length for google drive download ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Using requests module to download a file from google drive how to get the content length?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the content-length with the use of range

```
import re,requests

URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"
headers = {'Range':'bytes=0-'}

r = requests.get(URL,headers=headers,stream=True).headers['Content-Range']

#contleng=int(re.split('\W+',r))[-1]
contleng=int(r.partition('/')[-1]) #Thanks to Maritijn Pieters
contrange=int(re.split('\W+',r))[-2]
```

Comment: And why not split the Content-Range header on the slash? (`contlength = int(range.partition('/')[-1])`)

Comment: I just found myself a file big enough to trigger the transition from direct serve to a chunked transfer-encode and no content-length header. The range request is an interesting trick to use! It is rather specific to servers that support HTTP range requests, but something I'll keep in mind.