# How to connect pydrive with an Service Account

Tags: python-3.x, pydrive

Does anyone have any example or documentation how to connect a Service Account from Google Drive API with `pydrive`. I managed to do it with auth2 client.

Comment: Ever figured out how to make this work properly? It seems to work with the method suggested below at first, but then after 1 hour (3600 seconds) the session expires and it fails to renew (for some reason pydrive2 tries to use a different mode, spews "InvalidConfigError" looking for nonexistent file client_secrets.json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this should work, but it does not:

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gauth = GoogleAuth()
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
gauth.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_FILE, scope)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

UPDATE: error was caused by some missing permissions in google IAM.

Comment: Ever figured out how to make this work properly? It seems to work at first, but then after 1 hour (3600 seconds) the session expires and it fails to renew (for some reason pydrive2 tries to use a different mode, spews "InvalidConfigError" looking for nonexistent file client_secrets.json)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive/issues/107, PyDrive doesn't fully support this mode of operation.

PyDrive is also discontinued, and its fork PyDrive2 explicitly [supports Authentication with a service account](https://docs.iterative.ai/PyDrive2/oauth/#authentication-with-a-service-account).