# Read Google Sheet from Cloud function into Pandas DataFrame without making sheet public

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I managed to load a **sheet** into a **pandas dataframe** using `pd.read_csv(sheet_url)` but first I had to make the sheet **public**, which is not desirable.

Is there a way to **authenticate** somehow when running `pd.read_csv(sheet_url)` from the **cloud function**?

Comment: I found a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448029/how-to-use-google-sheets-api-while-inside-a-google-cloud-function) in which an answer from Martin Omander explains about your query.

Comment: That thread is using the Google Sheets API, I'm using pandas.read_csv().

Comment: You can use the [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) provided by GCP, and share the sheet only with that account rather than making it public.

Comment: @GouravB I tried sharing the sheet with the service account associated with the Cloud function but that is not working when running pd.read_csv, have u tried it and it works?

Comment: Can you please include the repo code and the error message.

Comment: The code is the one shared. I can’t share the sheet url, but i tried the same code with the sheet as public and it works.

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in pandas API like one for [Google Big Query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html)

Comment: I want to use pd.read_csv if possible, if not possible maybe another alternative implemented in Python

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting below the different approaches which you can try to resolve your query:

GCP provides [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) for sharing the sheet only with that account rather than making it public and steps for that are:
Create the service account.
Save the service account key
Create an API key
Save the API key
Grant spreadsheet access to the service account
Here is the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which you can perform to get yourself familiar with the official Python APIs for Google Drive. Additionally, you can refer to how to access Google Sheet using OAuth and Python API as mentioned [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-access-google-sheet-data-using-the-python-api-and-convert-to-pandas-dataframe-5ec020564f0e).

Pandas support the Google Cloud [BigQuery APIs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html) including Authenticating with a Service Account, but similar out-of-box APIs are not available for Google Drive/Sheets. However, you can look at this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63948118/16313960) on how to achieve this using pandas.

I’ve found a [guide](https://sempioneer.com/python-for-seo/google-sheets-with-python/#Authenticating_With_Google_Sheets_With_Pyghseets) to Google Sheets with Python which can help, it uses a python package called pygsheets.