# How to download file from one drive/google drive

Tags: python

I need to download a file from onedrive or google drive using wget or a faster method!

I've tried lots of code i could find on the internet but have not had any luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: download files from google drive using url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url)

Comment: suggest you show us the code , to proove that  you did research on microsoft or google provided api

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me to download a non-protected-link file:

1. Go to your OneDrive
2. Click on the share link and copy. It will look like: `https://.../EvZJeK2tIMOs54OA?<other-stuff>`
3. Append `download=1` after `?`  looking like `https://.../EvZJeK2tIMOs54OA?download=1`

Now you can use it with `wget` like:

`wget https://.../EvZJeK2tIMOs54OA?download=1 -O <output-file-name\>.<extension\>`

Note: The `-O` (capital `O`) is to define an output name otherwise it will have `EvZJeK2tIMOs54OA?download=1` as the file name.