# Download folder from Google drive to colab notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I Have an dataset folder of size 690Mo in my google drive, I would to copy the hole dataset on my google colab notebook to train my model, but the process of copying is very long, so how I can download the folder from Google drive with use of python script ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: download files from google drive using url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you have too many files on the root directory of Google Drive or in the dataset folder.

> If you have too many files and folders in root directory, then you
> should clean up and sort it in less folders.

> If you have many files in dataset folder, then try the following
> solutions:
>
> 1. Make a compressed file of your dataset folder and save it to drive. Then while running copy that compressed file (will take less than a
>    minute for 690Mb) and extract it in Colab.
> 2. Upload your dataset to any other platform (say OneDrive, Mega, etc.), get the link, and download on Colab using that link.