# InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'No files matched pattern:

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When I am running the following code on Google colab,

```
tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Experiment/train/*.jpg')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8d9cebdfe01f> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Experiment/train/*.jpg')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in Assert(condition, data, summarize, name)
    162           op=None,
    163           message="Expected '%s' to be true. Summarized data: %s" %
--> 164           (condition, "\n".join(data_str)))
    165     return
    166 

InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'No files matched pattern: /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Experiment/train/*.jpg'
```

I am stuck with this problem for the last two weeks, please help me out. Also, I have mounted the Google drive successfully before running the above lines of code.

Comment: That's because there is no such files or corrupted file or something.

Comment: There are many jpg files in the folder, and none of them is corrupted.

Comment: *.jpg does not sounds like a normal file name. Same as @M.Innat, the path is probably not correct or there's something wrong with its access

Comment: The idea here is to read all image files with a jpg extension. Indeed, jpg is a valid extension. The path is also correct.

Comment: Find your current working directory using `os.getcwd()` and try using a relative path instead.

Comment: @DavidThery `*.jpg` is a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). 
@Winter2019 Are you sure it's not supposed to be `My Drive` instead of `MyDrive` ? (you might have to escape the space)

Comment: @Kishore I am doing the same thing: first, I found the path using %pwd and then used that path.

Comment: @DavidThery: MyDrive is correct as I have used it many times in the past, and it works fine.

Comment: A snapshot of the colab file view will help. I do this regularly. And I also use `google_drive_downloader`[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url) if the file is too big.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some invalid characters in your filenames, like: .,*
Removing these characters resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to this post but I have also faced this issue. The issue was with the filepath.

Try changing the filepath from

```
tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Experiment/train/*.jpg')
```

to

```
tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./content/gdrive/MyDrive/Experiment/train/*.jpg')
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is the example I am working with.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

def load_image(filepath):
    raw_img = tf.io.read_file(filepath) 
    img_tensor_int = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw_img, channels=3)
    img_tensor_flt = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_tensor_int, tf.float32)
    return img_tensor_flt, img_tensor_flt

def load_dataset(split):
    print('/content/drive/MyDrive/CelebAsubset/'+split+'/*.jpg')
    train_list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/drive/MyDrive/CelebAsubset/'+split+'/*.jpg', shuffle=False)
    train_ds = train_list_ds.map(load_image)
    return train_ds

train_ds = load_dataset('train')
val_ds = load_dataset('val')

test_ds = load_dataset('test')
```