# How to download pdf file from google drive with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, download

I have a bunch of files like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97E3t0HAaIjbDQwRU9IMnVnTUU/view?resourcekey=0-UjUBZF42Qir5uC_8gt0AMw) that I have to download. I already have a code that allowed me to download a bunch of pdfs in other websites using direct links but not here. This is the code:

```
def download(url, file_name):
    get_response = requests.get(url,stream=True,verify=False)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in get_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    return file_name
```

If I use this on the link above I get an empty file. How can I download this embedded pdf from google drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url)

Comment: @KJ But then where in the source code of the page is the pdf to download? I looked everywhere and couldn't find it