# Download file from Google Drive using Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am using python 3.10.5 and wondering **how I can download a file from Google Drive**?

I found some answers like using [gdown](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url). However, for my python version gdown is not supported.

Does anyone have a working way of downloading Google drive files using python 3.10?

Answer (score 0):

***Download files with Drive API.***

It should be possible to utilize the sample from the Python Quick-start from the official documentation to download files. I have a code based on it that allows me to download images:

```js
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import requests
import io
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


def creds():
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return creds
    

def download(creds, real_file_id):
    try:
         # create drive api client
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        file_id = real_file_id

        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')

    return file.getvalue()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    file = open("test.jpg","wb")
    file.write(download(creds(), "ID of the Image"))
```

You only need to have the ID of the file that you need to download and paste it for testing at the end of the sample code.

Make sure to have created the credential and followed the quick-start process to have Google Drive under Python.

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#python