# Python: Download Google Doc as Odt

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to download a Google doc as an `.odt`-file. There's a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38511444/25282) on how to download normal files from Google Drive.

I want to download the Doc with Python, because I then want to continue to work with it within my slave.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @EvilReboot I explicitly linked that In my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Download Google Workspace Documents**

There are two things that I would like to clarify:

One important thing to note is that in order to download Google Workspace documents you would need to export them to a file type that allows download.

The Drive API does support OpenDocument. A sample of my code to export to `.odt` from an ID of a Google Doc:

````
```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


def main():

    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        file_id = "fileID_in_Google_Drive"

        data = service.files().export(fileId=file_id, mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text").execute()
        if data:
            filename = 'your-file-name.odt'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as pdf_file:
                pdf_file.write(data)
   
    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        file = None



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
````

You can change the:

> file_id = "fileID_in_Google_Drive"

With the ID of a Google Doc to run the test and verify it. This allowed me to modify and test the `.odf`. Editing the MIME type to `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula`. This would throw the error:

> An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileID_in_Google_Drive/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.oasis.opendocument.formula returned "The requested conversion is not supported.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'The requested conversion is not supported.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'convertTo'}]">

Confirming that the Drive API V3 does not support the export to `.odf`.

As an alternative you can document and request a feature for the API, you should be able to open an Issue tracker:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106

**Edit:**

**PIP imports:**

- pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
- pip install --upgrade google-auth-httplib2
- pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib

**References**

- https://www.openoffice.org/framework/documentation/mimetypes/mimetypes.html
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-export-formats
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads

Comment: Thank you. I actually meant odt and somehow misremembered the abbreviation I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you add the necessary `pip` imports?

Comment: They should be the ones available over here and you can also follow the steps: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python // I would also edit it.