# How to pull the most recent file from a Google Drive folder using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm looking to pull a file named 'Export_2023_07_28.xlsx' from a folder called 'SKU' on my personal Google Drive into a pandas data frame. My intention is to transform the data and output the data frame to a xlsx/csv file onto my local machine, so the original file in the Google Drive will not be altered.

The folder 'SKU' is updated with a new xlsx file bi-weekly, so I will need to pull the LATEST file.

I've been using the *os* and *requests* python libraries to accomplish this but to no avail. This is my first experience with trying to pull a file from Google Drive, so I've been struggling with this. I usually use python for data analysis, but I'm trying to learn how to utilize APIs and establishing connections between platforms.

As previously mentioned, I'm using the *os* and *requests* libraries to get this to work. As to why, I was following a tutorial similar to my ask in hopes that I can work it into a solution.

At the moment, I just trying to pull *any* file from the SKU folder and build from there, but I'm being hit with a 'Bad Request' (400) or a 'Page Not Found' (404: when I enter the report gid) error. I'm currently using Python 3.9.12.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written to download from google drive so we can troubleshoot. From that we can troubleshoot and help connect the dots. Also, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225272/2221001) helpful.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)