# How to access files on Google Drive via Google Colab notebook (.ipynb)?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded all the files I need to train (fine-tune) an object detection model on my Google Drive account. There, I have opened an ipynb file via google colab and I need to run some scripts to initialize things and run training.

But I ran into a problem of not knowing how to access the files that I uploaded from the notebook. The notebook is created in the same directory of the scripts that I need to run.

When I execute `!ls` I get only one `datalab` folder in return, and `!pwd` returns `/content`.

I want to know if there's a way to access all the files I have uploaded to my google drive account. I may be doing the wrong thing trying to train a model this way, but I don't know any other. So, please help :).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Colab: how to read data from my google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive)

Answer (score 2):

Here what I use to download a file from Google Drive to Google Colab file system, substitute `fileId` value with your Drive file id.

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

fileId = '1234567890dcz4qL-JQtYqX9ZXUt7JXe'
fileName = fileId
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': fileId})
downloaded.GetContentFile(fileName)
```

To get Drive file id look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855034/9250875).