# Google Drive Public Links Concurrent Limits

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been using Google Drive files shared with "View Everybody with Links" to store images that are included in transactional emails (like header images, etc).

I get the links using the SDK, and my links look like:
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id={somefileId}.

This is basically the technique from [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website/11466763#11466763).

This works... most of the time.

Sometimes I get reports of users not being able to download the images. I cannot figure it out what is going on, but I believe it is that there is a limit on how many concurrent or maybe accumulative requests can be done on a given link and/or user account.

I am looking for documentation that confirms this. My specific question is: does anybody know the quota limits imposed by Google Drive? (if you have a link to official information it would be great).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem for me,
It seems Google drive has limits when sharing files,
I hope this link will be useful,
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494827?hl=en
The help does not indicate whether the limits are daily, always ....
Regards