# Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in One Drive on a website

Tags: onedrive

How do I access/display files like images which are stored in One Drive on a public website. It is the same question for Google Drive here: [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website/19029095#19029095)

Answer (score 0):

Click on image, click View Original.