# How to displayimage from google drive at page.html?

Tags: html, image, google-drive-api

i trying use image from **google drive** at my *html-page*, i shared image and copied link to file.
[image]
and pasted it to *image* tag:

```
<img ng-src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0etQtBsI2KmVGVmYjNOSS15VVk" />
```

but it don't displays:

[image]

may be somebody knows how i can resolve it ? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work, the link you are using is an html page.

Taken from question [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Replace the `open` part of the link with `uc` and it will work. It will become `<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B0etQtBsI2KmVGVmYjNOSS15VVk" />`

Answer (score 1):

Per October 2021, I tried this way and this is worked for me.

1. Make sure your file permission is "Anyone with the link (Anyone on the internet with this link can view)".
2. Copy your link. For example: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ABKic44czHx37335mQSfFzOuX4WUk3II/view?usp=sharing`.
   This is my image:
   [image: My screenshot]
3. Open this link in the new tab of your browser.
4. After that, click in this image and drag into new tab. You will see a drop down arrow like in this picture:
   [image: Drag & drop]
5. Copy the link from this new tab. For my link it will become: `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/2OwFYkb4hQl4f7HmBoS__I1k6MUy7Vxz2dYrYHkL6J-VegICE-Ie81ZKfKF-vvqv8GQ8S5A4XxIMYaEvWpI=w3360-h1720-rw`