# favicon for web app doesnt load by apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm looking for way to add favicon in html page of apps script's project.
Trying this way gives me blue right arrow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDallYn2cQg

What I do wrong? The image has 'png' format and located in google drive.

And on load the page I get the mistake with CORB

[image]

apps script code here:

```js
function doGet(e){

var htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
return htmlServ.evaluate()
            .setFaviconUrl('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LbW6xr-vKAD-pkZkvJP_Z-Cf7ezh9vVJ/view?usp=sharing#.png')
            .setTitle('CLR: PACKING')
            .addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0")
            .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
            
}


Html code here:
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CLR: PACKING</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <form novalidate>
                <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
            <div class="dws-input">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="del" type="button" disabled>&lt;======СБРОС</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name= "username" placeholder= "Логин:" autofocus > 
                        <label for="tLogin">Логин:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  novalidate id="tTable" name= "text" placeholder= "Номер стола:" >
                        <label for="tTable">Номер стола:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text"  novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name= "text" placeholder= "Заказ:" >
                    <label for="tOrder">Заказ:</label>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222645/555121

Comment: @ Kos  thank you  showed me right way in html without doGET <link rel="icon" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[ID...]#.png" type="png"> thank you very much!!!

Comment: sorry, I did mistake, it loads from doGet, from html it doesn't load