# ipython get an image from google cloud

Tags: python, url, ipython, png, jupyter-notebook

I would like to read an image stored in google drive from an ipython notebook. I tried already using Image and requests as:

```
import requests
from ipywidgets import Image
img  = Image(requests.get("https://drive.google.com    /open?id=XXXX4"))
type(img)
img
```

but the image is broken. Or if I use the url input explicitly:

```
img  = Image(url=https://drive.google.com    /open?id=XXXX4")
type(img)
img
```

The '.com=....' is recognized as the format of the image so I got:

```
ValueError: Cannot embed the '.com=...' image format
```

Also I tried to directly import the file using requests library but in that case the whole html is returned which is not what I want... Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `Image` from `IPython.display`?

Comment: same thing... broken image

Comment: This issue is only with Google Drive? Images from other websites are shown without any problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Comment: The problem is that using the Image function the extension is taken from the link. Now since the link doesn't contain the extension (jpg , png etc.) the function return the ValueError. Alternatively the requests method retrieve an html which is not the way to go

Comment: [Docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=Image#IPython.display.Image) say that you can specify `format` of an image.

Comment: Same goes for `ipywidgets`: [link](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html?highlight=Image#Image), but it seems that you can't read images from url with it.

Comment: ok I think google drive is changing the access of the url any time I open the file so the request library gets a forbidden message ... I guess I can't use google drive

Comment: Did you see the link I sent above? Alternative ways of hosting are described [here](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/reminder-turn-down-of-google-drive-web.html)

Comment: yes I did and I did but if you see at the end the only way to make it work on drive it would be to save the image without the extension... don't like that I'm trying dropbox