# Folder authentication based on googlesheet url or id

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, google-sheets, cpanel

I am trying to load an image into a cell using `image` function. The function is working well if the image is stored in public url.

My problem is my photos are stored in google drive and the actual link to the image keeps on changing. Even if you make the folder accessible to anyone with link, it is very unstable. It works when I update the photo url but next day when I open it photos are no longer working and need to update the url again.

My only option now is to upload the photos in a public folder in my cpanel server but it is too open.

Is there a way to implement authentication in a cpanel folder to allow only specific google sheets have access to the folder?

htaccess perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675890/9337071) doesn't work?

Comment: It works for now. I will check tomorrow if it won't change and update here. Thanks