# Get pictures from google drive folder with javascript to my website

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I would like to be able to take pictures from folder on google drive and run it on my website.

I have a java script slider but I have no idea how to take the pictures from google drive until now I took it from local folder.

This is the java script:

```
<img class="mySlides myImg"  src="Images/Image_01.jpeg" alt="Pasta, Tasty" width="620" height="340">

 <!-- Slider Image Script -->
                 <script>
                 var slideIndex = 1;
                 showDivs(slideIndex);

                 function plusDivs(n) {
                 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
                 }

                 function currentDiv(n) {
                 showDivs(slideIndex = n);
                 }

                 function showDivs(n) {
                 var i;
                 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
                 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                     x[i].style.display = "none";  
                  }
                 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                 dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
                 }
                 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
                 }
                 </script>
```

Comment: u would need to use google drive api for that https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/

Comment: I read it but I am not sure I to use it

Comment: here's more of a detail, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website

Comment: It is old and answers like : https://googledrive.com/host/<folderID>/<filename> does not work anymore

Comment: Moreover I want it to take automatically pictures from there and display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosting resources from Google Drive [has long been discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092), but for the images, you can try using the [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to fetch the [webContentLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) which you can then display in your img src like:

```
< img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID_HERE&export=download" >
```

Comment: ok but how can I call a folder on google drive because I want it to display all images auto (also new images that I add to this folder)

Comment: maybe open a new question with along with what you have tried.