# How to get full path to file on Google Drive?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm making simple project which uploads files on Google Drive. Then i need to "show" this files to users, by using html < img > tag for this i need to know URL to my image. But i don't know how to get it. I've tried to add

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/

to my Google Drive File's id, but it hadn't worked although i can see the image in my browser by using this method, also i checked code of this page  and found this [image]

As you may see, i found my image, but my fileid isn't similar to id underlined at the photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of methods as posted in [SO 10311092](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website), some of which are already deprecated. However, there seems to be one that still works as of October 2018. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191355) by ctf0 is very simple.

> here is how from @
>   https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/yU_yF9SI_z0/discussion
>
> 1- upload ur image
>
> 2- right click and chose "get sharable link"
>
> 3- copy the link which should look like
>
> https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxx
>
> 4-change the open? to uc? and use it like
>
> `<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxxx">`
>
> - its recommended to remove the http: or https: when referencing    anything from the web to avoid any issues with ur server.

Or you can also try Google's [method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads): providing users direct access to a file via the URL in the `webViewLink` property.