# Where to store static images (e.g., app logo) for a Google App script?

Tags: google-apps-script, static-files

I am new to Google App Script and opened the tutorial to create a button add-on that creates a cat image with a text:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart

The script manifest of this sample App includes a link to a logo image (a paw) which is displayed on the right-hand side. The logo image is hosted by a static website from Google:

```js
"logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png",
```

I tried to replace this image by a different logo:
[new logo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMKRv.png)

I uploaded this image to my Google Drive, with a shareable link (no password, everyone can view).

[sharing permissions of the new logo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeWOl.png)

Here is the new line in the manifest with the new URL for the logo

```js
      "logoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OXYP8c2io6lBy2KroFAqBINPUBpH-uqr/view?usp=sharing",
```

This didn't work and shows a white square instead of the PNG image (same size, same format).

[new logo image doesn't isn't displayed in the App menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHWDO.png)

I assume Google Drive is not the ideal place to store static images. Is there a simple way to store static images (e.g., the app logo) for a Google App Script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is considered "simple" or not, but the [Google Cloud Platform Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free) is not hard to set up, and [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) should do what you want.

Your "logoUrl" would then be at something like:

https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-project-bucket/my-image.png

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the first url and the second, you'll see the first ends with .png which is a type of image file. Your google url is different. And as a result, requires a little more work.

You need to get a shareable link and then tweak that link to just include just the id. More through [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website).