# Google drive image gives 403 forbidden error

Tags: image, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I am using google drive to show images on a website.
I'm using the following url to show the images:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileId}
```

It works fine on most occasions, but some users don't see the images and get the following error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

The image files and folders on the google drive are shared with everybody with a link to see.
The problem does not seem browser related.

Anyone an idea how to fix this? Are there some things I forgot to do (do I need some kind of API key in the link)?

Comment: Please include the full error message.   Also note Google drive is not a file hosting service it is not intended for this use case.

Comment: Have you ever been able to make it work consistently? I have tried `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={id}` and `https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/{id}` and `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/u/0/d/{id}` and all them occasionally return 403 when used on my website, but work fine used directly in the browser from the address bar. The images are shared in Google Drive with "Everyone can view" permission.

Answer (score 4):

As of today I have the same issue. (just like a few months back when Google ended the classic sites, which I (mis)used as an image repository.)

After I cleared all cookies from the browser, the images were visible again.
So that solved this problem.

If your problem persists, you should change the URL.

This URL gives a 403 err:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={img-ID}
```

Change that to:

```
https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/{img-ID}
```

For example: setting a favicon in a WebApp:

```
return template.evaluate()
  .setFaviconUrl('https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1qMrq5o54jhg5jedu9fLtzUG4dF1ijKZT1#.ico')
```

Answer (score 4):

I found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143719/717372) that the best solution to share an image from google drive is using this url:

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/{ID_OF_THE_FILE}`

Syntax example: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1z-3moeybmtxqhyjWWN8PvKIZizI6yw6B

Visual proof that this solution still work:

[image]

Another advantage, you could resize the images on the fly:

- to set a max **width** of 300 (for example) by appending `=w300` to the url. Example: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1z-3moeybmtxqhyjWWN8PvKIZizI6yw6B=w300
- same with max **height** by appending `=h300`. Example: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1z-3moeybmtxqhyjWWN8PvKIZizI6yw6B=h300

Disadvantage (discovered after writing the answer): if the image size is bigger than a limit, the api doesn't return the original image but a downsized version ☹️. The original size of the image example is 3317x2221 but the image served has a size of 1600x1071. So maybe not a solution suitable for everything...

If you have a lot of files to share and to get the urls, [my solution to generate image urls for all files of a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360080/717372) could help to get them easily.

Comment: @uffa14 so maybe you should upvote the answer to show others that it has value (and especially as it is a late and new answer, so it really needs it...)

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problem working with Ionic Angular, in the lastest versions you should use [https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/{img-ID}](https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/%7Bimg-ID%7D) as Edso said and it solves the problem. Consider that the images will only load if you have a logged google account, otherwhise the status of the response will be 302 and image will never load.

Answer (score 0):

ok i know i am late... and my answer may not work for you but it did for me.

i was getting the 403 forbidden error when i used this link
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={file-id}`

the problem wasn't with the link. but with the file access. so, earlier when i viewed the file access it was like this
[image: link with restricted access]

and the response in html file was like this 
[image: 403 forbidden error]

but if i just click on restricted and change it to anyone, the html was able to fetch it and it worked.

[image: link with public access]

and then the html response was able to fetch it with a couple of redirects which were automatic 
[image: file was able to be fetched]

**make sure public access is set to viewer or anyone who knows how to open devtools will be able to comment or edit your file.

also i have shared original link as i have already deleted the file on that link before publishing this answer.**