# Background Image not working with this following code

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This is my code and somehow I am not able to get the image loaded.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"


function Section() {
  return (
    <Wrap>
      
    </Wrap>
  )
}

export default Section

const Wrap = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMeRfE2OEktMOGVlgA1TwJKNj1teuLtG/view?usp=sharing;
`
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should look at the [syntax for a CSS background-image rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Answer (score 1):

For the direct link of an image stored in Google Drive:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=file's ID`

So the URL of your image should be:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1rMeRfE2OEktMOGVlgA1TwJKNj1teuLtG`.

Then, use it via CSS `background-image: url('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1rMeRfE2OEktMOGVlgA1TwJKNj1teuLtG')`

See, [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `background-image`, you should use `url()` with URL.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMeRfE2OEktMOGVlgA1TwJKNj1teuLtG/view?usp=sharing");
```

**Edit**

Your Url is not Image so you can not load image with your Google Drive Url.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the wrong value for the CSS property.

✓ Use This:

```css
background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMeRfE2OEktMOGVlgA1TwJKNj1teuLtG/view?usp=sharing");
```

✘ Instead of your this code:

```
background-image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMeRfE2OEktMOGVlgA1TwJKNj1teuLtG/view?usp=sharing;
```

As in your current question I see you have forgotten to put `url()`.