# Display image in HTML page served by Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

Good afternoon all;

I have a google spreadsheet which is populated by a Qualtrics form, where the user can upload a photo.

Using Apps Script, I have created a CRUD database that is accessed via a google sites page (html form).  All is working great, but I'd like to display the photo that the user uploaded in their record; the URL to the image is saved in a column on the spreadhsheet.

The thing is, I'm not a very worthy 'coder' and I can't figure out how to make this happen.

I'm accessing my data like this: Note that I have removed a good portion of the code to save space.

Code.gs

```
function getFormValues(formObject) {

  if (formObject.responseID && checkID(formObject.responseID)) {
    var values = [[formObject.responseID.toString(),
    formObject.permitNumber,
    formObject.dateOfIssue,
    formObject.photoLink, <<<this is where the URL would be pulled in. Column Q in the spreadsheet.`
```

DataTable.html

```
function populateForm(records){
    document.getElementById('responseID').value = records[0][0];
    document.getElementById('permitNumber').value = records[0][1];
    document.getElementById('photoLink').value = records[0][16];
```

...I just don't know what to do after this point...

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (usually the best is to start from scratch having in mind to add the minimal code lines required to reproduce the problem). Also please avoid "chit-chat" (like "Good afternoon all") including information about yourself (you could add that in your user profile) Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. Also add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests, and I have an option for you to use Google Apps Script and the formula [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333).

Since I didn't have much information on your setup, like where the files are uploaded, which is the format of the URL, etc. I made a test environment using Google Forms, the files uploaded to Google Drive, and  Apps Script.

With the formula:

```
=IMAGE("URL", [mode], [height], [width])
```

For the test, I use mode 4, which allows you to specify the size of the image. You can use either of the modes:

- 1 resizes the image to fit inside the cell, maintaining the aspect ratio.
- 2 stretches or compresses the image to fit inside the cell, ignoring the aspect ratio.
- 3 leaves the image at its original size, which may cause cropping.
- 4 allows the specification of a custom size.

The `height` and `width` needs to be in pixels.

When you use a Google Form to upload an image, you get an URL with the following format:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=[ID_OF_THE_FILE]
```

There is a trick to display images from Google Drive into Google Sheets using the image formula. You need the URL with the format: (I got this idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143719/17390145) post)

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/[ID_OF_THE_FILE]
```

So the script that I created modifies the URL in the column of the image from:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=[ID_OF_THE_FILE]
```

To:

```
=IMAGE("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/[ID_OF_THE_FILE]", 4, 60, 60)
```

And place it in the cell in the column. However, you can place it in the same column as the current URL too.

Here is the sample code:

```
function testImage() {
  // Identifies the sheet link to the Google Sheet and the tab you will be working with
  // you can also use const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  //                                              .getSheetId("[ID_OF_THE_SHEET]"); 
  // if the Script is not bound to the sheet. 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  // Gets the range and the values where the URLs of the images are located. 
  // in my example there are in column B
  let range_1 = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues().flat();

  // Filters the rows without values or empty
  range_1 = range_1.filter((element) => {return (element !== '')});

  // Start of the loop to run on each row with URLs
  for (let i=0; i< range_1.length ; i++){
    let row = range_1[i];

    // For this sample, I replace the URL with the word "Done" to prevent duplicates later on in the Script
    // This can be skipped or replaced place, in a different location. 
    if (row != "Done"){

      // Replace the URL from https://drive.google.com/open?id=[ID_OF_THE_FILE] 
      // to =IMAGE("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/[ID_OF_THE_FILE]
      let temp_imageURL = row.toString().replace('https://drive.google.com/open?id=', 
      '=IMAGE("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/');

      // However, the process is not complete yet, we need to complete the formula
      // so we added the last part ",4,60,60) to the URL 
      // making it "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/[ID_OF_THE_FILE]",4,60,60)
      let imageURL = temp_imageURL+'",4,60,60)';

      // place the complete formula in the current iteration, row 3 (which is row C)     
      sheet.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(imageURL);

      // replace the current URL in Row 2 (which is row B) with the word "Done"
      sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue("Done");
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333)
- [Replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: @John Blades. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)