# Google App Script (html) - open image from Google Drive in iOS/Apple

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to show an image from Google Drive (permission anyone with the link).
My code is:

file Code.gs
`function doGet(request) { return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate(); }`

file index.html
(...)
`<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[IMG_ID]" width="50px" height="auto" alt="img">`
(...)

On android device it works perfectly.
On Chrome Apple iMac it also works. But on iPhone (Chrome and Safari), the image does not open.

Would anyone have a solution?

How display image (iOS) from Google Drive using App Script.

Comment: Try <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[IMG_ID] > or <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[IMG_ID] >

Comment: @MetricRat It didn't work either.  1) <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[IMG_DI]"> works on Chrome Apple iMac and Android. 
2) <img src="drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[IMG_DI]"> does not work.
3)  <img src="drive.google.com/uc?id=[IMG_DI]">  does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the url of the picture
from "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[IMG_ID]"
to "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/[IMG_ID]"

I found that information here:
[Display image in HTML page served by Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225793/display-image-in-html-page-served-by-apps-script?r=SearchResults_Semantic)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!